# get youtube single video data api and json decode in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, youtube-api, cakephp-1.3, youtube-data-api

Ever since Google changed YouTube to API3.0  I can't fetch videos anymore. I can't get video id and api key to apiURL

```
$video_id = // I stript it from url
$apiKey = Configure::read('YouTube.v3.0.privateKey'); // hidden in bootstrap


$apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$video_id&key=$apiKey';
```

and on `debug($apiURL);` I'm getting

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$video_id&key=$apiKey

anyone can help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you share the api call made to get the data?

Comment: that's where the call is $apiURL

Answer (score 1):

if you want little snippet, here we go, it works for me on cakephp1.3 application

```
$apiURL = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={$video_id}&key={$apiKey}");

$youtubeResponse = json_decode($apiURL, true);

$youtube_data = $youtubeResponse['items'];
// debug($youtube_data);

$youtube_data_title =  $youtube_data['0']['snippet']['title'];
$youtube_data_description = $youtube_data['0']['snippet']['description'];
$youtube_data_thumbnail = $youtube_data['0']['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];

    $this->set('youtube_data_title', $youtube_data_title);
    $this->set('youtube_data_description', $youtube_data_description);
    $this->set('youtube_data_thumbnail', $youtube_data_thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not evaluate variables in single quotes. Your URL should be places in double quotes:

```
$apiURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$video_id&key=$apiKey";
```

to get variables replaced with values.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) good read about outputing text in PHP